# bind and pass 2 values commandArgument and hidden field, ERROR

Tags: asp.net, repeater, hidden-field, commandargument

Using a repeater to display a list,(with 'remove' btn beside each record) click 'remove' and it removes from the list. Im passing 'id' using commandArgument, I want to pass another value...'company name' tried it through text, but not sure how to pass it...then in code behind I use companyName to get contractorId, (company name for the contractor

```
<td>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Bind ("id") %>' runat="server" OnCommand="RemoveSubContractor" CssClass="bottomhyperlink">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnCompanyName" value='<%#Bind("Company_Name")%>'>
</td>
```

In code behind:

```
HiddenField hdnCompanyName = (HiddenField)e.CommandArgument.ToString("hdnCompanyName); 
string companyName = hdnCompanyName.Value;
```

Then problem is coming from code behind after the e.commandArgument I tried to do .findControl but it wouldnt allow me...ANyone know what I am missing? thank you

Comment: Have a look at my edit, I've added an alternative (perhaps better?) way how this can be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the repeater items, get the item with the id passed through by `CommandArgument='<%# Bind ("id") %>'` and call `FindControl()` to get the company name, here's an example:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdCompanyName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>' />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnCommand="Save" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text="Save" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class RepeaterExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee{ Id="1",CompanyName="Company 1"},
                new Employee{ Id="2",CompanyName="Company 2"}
            };
            Repeater1.DataSource = employees;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Save(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        string companyName = string.Empty;

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            Label lblId = item.FindControl("lblId") as Label;
            if (lblId.Text.Equals(id))
            {
                companyName = (item.FindControl("hdCompanyName") as HiddenField).Value;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(companyName);
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Perhaps even a better solution would be to pass both *id* and *company name* to the `CommandArgument` this will avoid extra processing created by looping through the repeater:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdCompanyName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>' />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnCommand="Save" CommandArgument='<%# String.Format("{0},{1}",Eval("ID"),Eval("CompanyName"))  %>' Text="Save" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code behind:**

Just split the string and there are both your parameters!

```
protected void Save(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string [] arguments = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');
    string id = arguments[0];
    string companyName = arguments[1];
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write all that man...great help

Comment: 3 years later and this helped me find the value of a textbox inside of my repeater in the click event of a button...nice work!